# Design tool for ASP.Net Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for some tool so that I can design my web pages(layout, color etc...). Does anything exist like that? (Other than Visual Studio, Dreamweaver...)
(I dont want to write css for now)

Comment: Do you mean other than Visual Web Developer, Visual Studio, Dreamweaver, etc?

Comment: Are there user requirements? Or any idea of a perfered meathod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools used to create the design are usually Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop or equivalents, these will help create the images and can build basic layouts.

You can use Dreamweaver or equivalent to build layouts but if you are doing a lot of databinding you may want to use visual studio too.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver I hear helps with that. I use Visual Studio and create CSS files.

Dreamweaver: http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/

Visual Studio: http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/

Answer (score 1):

How about Visual Web developer? You can download the express edition for free

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express (Free), Expression Web and lots more . Do you have any particular requirement?